# CORS Configuration for Azure AD B2C Page UI Customization

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-blob-storage

I'm using a custom page UI template for my Azure AD B2C sign in/sign up and I want to know what domain I need to use in `CORS` configuration in my Azure Blob Storage account.

Login page seems to come from `https://login.microsoftonline.com`. Is that the correct origin?

When I use the `StorageClient` command line tool Microsoft created for uploading my custom UI files to my Azure Blob Storage, I've noticed that it sets it to `*` for `Allowed Origins` which the documentation indicates as well. Here's the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom-dynamic#step-3-configure-cors-in-azure-app-service

I don't think this is really secure and I want to limit it to only those domains that are absolutely necessary.

I want to do this for two reasons, both of which are pretty important:

1. I want to keep security as tight as possible and allowing any origin doesn't seem secure.
2. More importantly, `CORS` is set at service level on Azure Blob Storage and not container level. I have other containers under the same storage account that contain user files. Those files should only be accessible from my app which creates a SAS to allow access to them. If I set the `Allowed Origins` for `CORS` to any, it will make my app less secure even though the protected files will still require a SAS. As I said before, I want to keep security as tight as possible.

So, the question is: what URL should I enter under `Allowed Origins` in my `CORS` configuration for Azure AD B2C? I don't just want to make the assumption that it's `https://login.microsoftonline.com` because Microsoft usually does a few redirects in their services and I want to make sure all the necessary origins are included.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should set the CORS origin to either `https://login.microsoftonline.com` or `https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com` if you are [using b2clogin.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin).

Comment: For me allowing just {tenant}.b2clogin.com in CORS settings did not work. But I think adding "https://" in front of the URL was what made it work.

Comment: yes, even if you add "/" after url like https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/ will give a problem. so be specific